# How do I prove this triangle congruence related problem??

Tags: geometry

Inside the triangle *ABC* there is a point *P* such that ∠*PAC* =∠*PBC* . The perpendicular foots from *P* to *AC* and *BC* are points *M* and *N*, respectively. Prove that the midpoint of the side *AB* is equidistant from the points *M* and *N*.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Even though no work is shown, this is quite an interesting problem. It falls without much difficulty to many types of bashes. The angle condition is weird, all that I have been able to do to interpret is is that the isogonal conjugate of $P$ is equidistant from $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, $D$, $E$ and $F$ are the mid-points of $BP$ and $AP$ respectively.

Our job is to prove that $DM=DN.$

Let $\angle PAC= \angle PBC = x$

Join the lines as shown.

Note that $DFPE$ is a parallelogram implies

$$\angle DFP=\angle DEP  \tag{1}$$

$$FP=DE \tag{2}$$

$$DF=EP  \tag{3}$$

$\because \Delta PMA$ and $\Delta PNB$ are right angled triangles,

$$FM=FA=FP \tag{4}$$  $$EN=EB=EP \tag{5}$$ and $$\angle NEP= \angle PFM = 2x  \tag{6}$$

$(1)$ and $(6) \implies \angle DFM = \angle DEN$

$(2)$ and $(4) \implies FM=DE$

$(3)$ and $(5) \implies DF=EN$

Hence $\Delta FDM \cong \Delta END$  (SAS)

$\therefore  DM=DN$